# str_to_map returns map<string,string>. How to make it return map<string,int>?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using str_to_map as:-

```
hive> select str_to_map("A:1,B:1,C:1");
OK
{"C":"1","A":"1","B":"1"}
```

As you can notice it is returning object of type map < string,string>. I want object of type map. Is there any way out? Can we typecast it in some way to map< string,int>?

Answer (score 2):

I stared at this and looked around for a while and didn't see much, but turns out it's quite simple -- just use `cast`:

```
select cast(str_to_map("A:1,B:1,C:1") as map<string, int>)
-- {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}
```

Comment: fails with syntax error:-  FAILED: ParseException line 1:41 cannot recognize input near 'map' '<' 'string' in primitive type specification

Comment: Hmm it's working perfectly well for me in Spark SQL which I had assumed is equivalent to HiveQL...

Comment: looks like it's not that similar, there might be subtle differences

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [map_remove_keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63300559/4740627) UDF:

```
> add jar hdfs:///lib/brickhouse-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;
> create temporary function map_remove_keys as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.MapRemoveKeysUDF';
> select map_remove_keys(map("", 0), array(""));
+------+
| _c0  |
+------+
| {}   |
+------+
```