# Insert empty MAP

Tags: sql, hive

Couldn't find this anywhere. I have a column of type MAP that may or may not have a value. Inserting `NULL` throws an error. Inserting `map()` throws an error as it inserts an empty `map<string, string>` and I need an `empty<int, int>`. How do I go about creating an empty map of type `<int, int>`

Comment: I wonder what is the reason of inserting empty map. How can you use it later practically? Isn't it better to insert NULL?

Comment: I agree. But inserting NULL throws an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create empty Map as follows:

```
select map(cast(null as int), cast(null as int))
```

Comment: This leads to 

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use null as map key.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to create empty `map<int, int>` as follows:

```
> create temporary function map_remove_keys as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.MapRemoveKeysUDF';
> select map_remove_keys(map(0, 0), array(0));
+------+
| _c0  |
+------+
| {}   |
+------+
```

Or use a UDAF(NOTE: it's an aggregate function):

```
> create temporary function collect as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';
> select collect(cast(null as int), cast(null as int));
+------+
| _c0  |
+------+
| {}   |
+------+
```

As a comparison:

```
> select map(cast(null as int), cast(null as int));
+--------------+
|     _c0      |
+--------------+
| {null:null}  |
+--------------+
```